# create a map from list in Scala

Tags: java, scala, scala-collections

I need to create a HashMap of directory-to-file in scala while I list all files in the directory. How can I achieve this in scala?

```
val directoryToFile = awsClient.listFiles(uploadPath).collect {
  case path if !path.endsWith("/") => {
    path match {
      // do some regex matching to get directory & file names
      case regex(dir, date) => {
          // NEED TO CREATE A HASH MAP OF dir -> date. How???
      }
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}
```

The method `listFiles(path: String)` returns a `Seq[String]` of absolute path of all files in the `path` passed as argument to the function

Comment: What does `listFiles` return?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Seq[String] which is a list of absolute paths for all files in the directory

Answer (score 0):

You can `filter` and then `foldLeft`:

```
val l = List("""/opt/file1.txt""", """/opt/file2.txt""")
val finalMap = l
                .filter(!_.endsWith("/"))
                .foldLeft(Map.empty[String, LocalDateTime])((map, s) =>
  s match {
    case regex(dir, date) => map + (dir -> date)
    case _ => map
  }
)
```

Comment: thanks! What about the "collect" method where I was filtering out some elements based on a certain criteria in the original code?

Comment: You can apply a `filter` before using `foldLeft`. Edited the answer.

Comment: thank you! Now, I minor update: there could be a situation that the same directory may have multiple files denoted by date: "dir1/2016-01-01.txt" and "dir1/2013-01-01/txt". In that case, I want the hashmap to only keep the value with the latest file date.. how can I use "max" function to  do that?

Comment: `+` on `immutable.Map` with the same key will override the previous entry.

Comment: See my solutions. I have added your "max" function.

Comment: `// Stuff` means `map`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to write more idiomatic Scala. Something like this:

```
val directoryToFile = (for {
    path <- awsClient.listFiles(uploadPath)
    if !path.endsWith("/")
    regex(dir, date) <- regex.findFirstIn(path)
} yield dir -> date).sortBy(_._2).toMap
```

Comment: What `sortBy` is for? `Map` in Scala is unordered.

Comment: You said you wanted only the last (most recent) date associated with each dir. This is the purpose of the sortBy statement. You can also remove that, if you do not need it.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
val regex =  """(\d)-(\d)""".r
val paths = List("1-2", "3-4", "555")

for {

  // Hint to Scala to produce specific type
  _ <- Map("" -> "")

  // Not sure why your !path.endsWith("/") is not part of regex
  path@regex(a, b) <- paths
  if path.startsWith("1")

} yield (a, b)

//> scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(1 -> 2)
```

Slightly more complicated if you need `max`:

```
val regex =  """(\d)-(\d)""".r
val paths = List("1-2", "3-4", "555", "1-3")

for {
  (_, ps) <-
    ( for {
        path@regex(a, b) <- paths
        if path.startsWith("1")
      } yield (a, b)
    ).groupBy(_._1)
} yield ps.maxBy(_._2)

//> scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(1 -> 3)
```